# Adding a Javascript Variable to an <area> href

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create an area shape within an image map that has a link dependent on a Javascript variable.

The code I am using for the area shape is

`<area shape="circle" coords="41,193,20" href= <script>document.write(quiz); </script>>`

But when I test it, it writes "`document.write(quiz);>`" on the page. How can I go about putting the variable "quiz" into the href tag?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: assign the attribute to your area into a javascript function,  don't do it from the html

Answer (score 0):

You can't embed html tags into one another.

You'll need to modify the href of the area tag using JavaScript.  Perhaps something like this:

```html
<area id="shape" shape="circle" coords="41,193,20" href="">
```

```js
var areaElem = document.getElementById("shape");
areaElem.href = quiz;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("area").click(function() {
     document.write(quiz);
});
```

I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to accomplish but based on your description I think this would work.